# How to set a local variable in angular from HTML?

Tags: angular

I have a variable in my `ts` file:

```
 currentItem:any;
```

I have div which is generated based on collection, also it has a `pipe` filter on that.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of collection | search: searchText;">
// some content
</div>
```

I want to set value of `currentItem` to `item[0]` from HTML dynamically.

So everytime filter gets apply to collection `currentItem` will always be set to the `first item` of `collection`.

Can we do this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you can do this in your ts file. is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same search pipe in your component as well. Add search pipe to your modules provider array like this first

```
providers :[SearchPipe]
```

Inject the search pipe in your component like this

```
constructor(private searchPipe: SearchPipe) {}
```

Hope your searchText is set from input an field. On its change event you can set the  property currentItem like this

```
onSearchTextChange(event){
   this.searchText = event.target.value
   const currentItem = this.searchPipe.transform(collection , this.searchText )
   this.currentItem = currentItem.length > 0 ? currentItem[0] : [];
}
```